# Create SSRS Report With Vertical Table

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have a database that contains records of maps and when they are booked out and in. Simple enough, but I need to format this report in a very specific fashion.

There are 3 tables involved...

- **Map** - This is a table holding a record for each Map (e.g. 701, 702)
- **Map Bookings** - This is the table that holds a record for each time
  that the Map has been booked out. It has the following information: Booker Name (e.g James AAAbbott), Date Booked Out (e.g. 18 Oct 2014) Date Booked In (e.g. 6 Jan 2015)

Map Bookings are grouped by Map...

As a standard table, the results come out like this...

[image: Standard Table Layout]

I need it to come out like this...

[image: Desired Layout]

Each Map booking record would be listed below the map number as shown. The purple box on both shows the grouping by **Map** record. The Red box on each image shows an individual **Map Booking** record.

Any help you can give me would be fantastic. Excuse my inexperience in the topic when asking the above question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this. It takes a combination of a Matrix and Tablix. The later inside the former.

In design mode:

Add a Matrix to the report. Right-click the header of the first column of the empty Matrix, and choose Delete Columns. You don’t need that column.

From your dataset add the Map Number to the top cell in what is left of the Matrix you added above. This will group, and filter what we put into the cell below it.

From the Toolbox, drag and drop a Table into the bottom cell of the Matrix. Size the Matrix so it is a little bigger; this will make it easier to work with.

From the Tablix that is now in the Matrix, delete one column by right-clicking on it, and choosing Delete Columns. Doesn’t matter which one, you just need the 2 that are left. Delete the header row from the Tablix, too (right-click, Delete Rows).

Now, right-click the row header of the only row left in the Table, and choose Insert Row > Inside Group. Above or Below, doesn’t matter. You just need to 2 detail rows in the end.

Select the top 2 cells of the first row of the Tablix at the same time, right-click and choose Merge Cells.

Using the “add value” icon that you see when you hover your mouse pointer over the Tablix cell (see below toward the end of the center cell), add the Publisher Name from the dataset into this newly merged cell, add the Booked Out date into the first cell in the second row, and add the Booked In date to the other cell.

You should end up with something that looks like this (your dataset column name may be different):

[image]

Center the values, if you like. Set the format for the date to `dd-MMM-yyyy`.

Run the report, and you should see something that is getting close to what you need.

This is what I ended up with after a little formatting:

[image]

Your screen cap shows a bunch of empty rows/cell, so if you want to include that, you may have to union in a bunch of filler rows in the dataset, or just decide not to show them at all. That part I will leave up to you.

Hopefully, this will get you going in the right direction. Good luck!